# Deuteron nucleus, what is the wavefunction (including isospin)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, nuclear-physics, many-body, isospin-symmetry

What is the exact form of the wavefunction of the deuteron nucleus. Without electrons. Only neutron and proton combined to a total wavefunction. In the ket-notation I have something like this:

$| \psi_{deuteron ~ nucleus} ⟩ $ = $|n_1(l_1 \frac{1}{2}) j_1 m_1 \frac{1}{2} t_{z1}⟩$ $\bigotimes$ $| n_2(l_2 \frac{1}{2}) j_2 m_2 \frac{1}{2} t_{z2} ⟩$

Where 1 and 2 denote the proton and neutron, $ t_{z1} = \frac{1}{2} $ and $ t_{z2} = -\frac{1}{2} $
I am in the Lab frame. I am new in this topic (nucleus) and have not find any literature - I would be very happy if you have any recommandations - maybe some source where I can answer my question by myself.

So in short: what I am looking for is an exakt expression for $  ⟨r| \psi_{deuteron ~ nucleus} ⟩ $

**It is important to mention: I am in the lab frame, so the exact form of the deuteron wavefunction should depend on position $r_1$ and $r_2$ - not on the relative distance $r_1 - r_2$**

Comment: for the isospin see here http://hep.physics.wayne.edu/~harr/courses/7060/w03/lecture36.htm

Comment: thank you.unfortunately this is not what i am looking for:/

Comment: it tells you that it is just a single quantum number definition for the whole wavefunction of the nucleus.  if you google "wavefunction of deuteron" articles come up

Comment: Of course I already googled, but I did not find the deuteron wavefunction in the labframe. Only in the center of mass frame